# Finding a word in C++

Tags: c++, file, while-loop

I'm able to find the word in my list but I would like to display whatever number there is after the word has been found. My list has names followed by their GPA.

Example...

> ```
> michael 2.3
>
> Rachel 2.5
>
> Carlos 3.0
> ```

I would like to add the feature of displaying the number located after the name once it's found, I declared as int GPA but I'm not sure how to incorporated in my program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name;
    int offset;
    string line;
    int gpa;

    ifstream read_file;
    read_file.open("alpha.dat");
    cout << "Please enter your name: \n";
    cin >> name;

    if (read_file.is_open())
    {
        while (!read_file.eof())
        {
            getline(read_file, line);
            if ((offset = line.find(name)) != string::npos)
            {
                cout << "the word has been found: \n";
                // cout << name << gpa; example to display
            }
        }
        read_file.close();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: If each line contains both the name and the GPA, why can't you simply print `line` so it is displayed in its entirety?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you just need to output the line that you read from file:

```
while( getline(read_file, line) )
{
    if ((offset = line.find(name)) != string::npos) cout << line << endl;
}
```

Note that this isn't the best way to find the name.  For example, what if the user enters `Carl`?  It will be found as part of the string `Carlos`.  Or indeed, if they enter `2`, it will match parts of the GPA for multiple people.

What you can do here is use a string stream to read the name out.  Let's assume it contains no spaces, which would make it conform to how you are reading the user's name in.  You need to include `<sstream>`, by the way.  Note that you can read out the GPA as part of this same mechanism.

```
istringstream iss( line );
string thisname, gpa;

if( iss >> thisname >> gpa ) {
    if( thisname == name ) cout << name << " " << gpa << endl;
}
```

Finally, you may want to consider ignoring case when comparing strings.  The cheeky way is to just use the old C functions for this.  I know there are C++ methods for this, but none are as simple as good old `stricmp` from `<cstring>`:

```
if( 0 == stricmp(thisname.c_str(), name.c_str()) ) {
    cout << name << " " << gpa << endl;
}
```

Comment: I have one question but I want to pass gpa as a number and not a string because I want to be able to manipulate their gpa in the future. for example add or subtract..

Comment: Well, just read it as a `double` or `float` value instead of `string`.  You may need to consider rounding errors, as is common with these data types, but take it as it comes.  There are ways to deal with these using integers, if you're using exactly one decimal place all the time, but I think that's a larger topic which doesn't necessarily add value to this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can split `line` using stringstream, and store it into a vector, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name;
    int offset;
    string line;
    int gpa;

    ifstream read_file;
    read_file.open("alpha.dat");
    cout << "Please enter your name: \n";
    cin >> name;

    if (read_file.is_open())
    {
        while (!read_file.eof())
        {
            getline(read_file, line);
            if ((offset = line.find(name)) != string::npos)
            {
                cout << "the word has been found: \n";
                stringstream iss(line);
                vector<string> tokens;

                string str;

                while (iss >> str)
                    tokens.push_back(str);

                cout << tokens[0] << tokens[1];

            }
        }
        read_file.close();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `getline(read_file, line)...` with:

```
read_file >> name >> gpa;
if (name == search_name)
    cout << name << " " << gpa << endl;
```

Comment: You could, but this is not a very robust approach.  For data files that stipulate entries being line-based, it's a very good idea to use `getline` and then parse out the information with a string stream or similar.  That way, any errors in the file won't lead to wild behaviour of your program

Comment: I fail to see how using `getline` makes it any more robust.

Comment: If the file has a line that does not contain exactly two space-delimited items, the input will get out of sync with the file contents.  Also, you did not highlight the issue of the OP using `int` for the type of `gpa`, or suggest a different type.  If you use this verbatim, then the second time around the loop the name will be read as `.3` and the GPA input will fail.